# How can I detect that a command completed its output in a tty?

Tags: iphone, terminal, redirect, prompt, tty

I'm studying the code of Mobile Terminal which is a command line for iPhone.
The projects emulates a VT100 terminal.
I can monitor everything that goes through the terminal (ascii and control characters)
but I can't figure out how the terminal knows that a command completed its output. How
does the terminal know when to display the prompt again ? Is there a special control
character that every command sends when ending ?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you're running a *shell* in the terminal, because a VT100 doesn't show a prompt (AFAIK).

A shell creates a child process and executes the command there. The shell then simply waits until this child process is finished and then prints its prompt again.

An exception is when the command is run in the background (`some_command &`), the shell doesn't wait for the child to exit and immediately prints the prompt again.

Comment: Yes sorry there is a shell indeed associated to the terminal. So you think this is only process related ? The problem is I'm not sure I can track when a process ends because it is launched by the shell thread. I control the shell thread but not its children. I'll check the code about it.